# Merge elements in a list, if they are in a certain unicode range

Tags: python, list, unicode, list-comprehension

Say I have the following list

```
['\U0001f680', '\U0001f618', '\U0001f44d\U0001f3fe', '\U0001f1e6', '\U0001f1ee']
```

Now I want to merge two consecutive elements, if both of the elements are in the range of `U+1F1E6` to `U+1F1FF`, so the resulting list should be

```
['\U0001f680', '\U0001f618', '\U0001f44d\U0001f3fe', '\U0001f1e6\U0001f1ee']
```

So there are actually two questions:

1. How to check if a unicode is in between a certain range? Convert the unicode to a code point and compare those?
2. How to efficiently compare and create a new list from it? Some pythonic way with list comprehension?

I'm running Python 3.5 btw.

Comment: For 2. I'd use itertools.combinations.

Comment: @Hashirun Can you be sure that the string would always be single characters / atmost 2 characters?

Comment: @AnandSKumar One of the items in their list looks like it might be 2 *'\U0001f44d\U0001f3fe'*

Comment: So I think we need a definition of what an element of that list being in a certain unicode range means. With single code points it's obvious, the definition and the check, but what about unicode objects containing more than one code point‽  Should each code point be in the range?

Comment: If an element has more than one code point then it can be ignored. So only single code points should be compared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with unicode to understand your current request for range.. It's not as concise as it could be, but I've tried to account for cases where an element contains multiple characters. I've also given arbitrary unicode range..  hopefully this is of some help.

```
a = ['\U0001f680', '\U0001f618', '\U0001f44d\U0001f3fe', '\U0001f1e6', '\U0001f1ee']
aa = {x: ord(x.decode('unicode-escape')) if x.count('\\') < 2 else 1 for x in a}

low = 127460
high = 127475

[(y,x) if (high >= aa[x] >= low and high >= aa[y] >= low) else y for x,y in zip(aa.keys()[1:],aa.keys()[:-1])]
```